# How to convert a Json string to a class that has a list in Json.Net with C# when the json has an array one level deeper

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a C# Application in which I am using Json.Net from Nuget.
I get a json from my server which I need to convert into a C# object and with a few modifications I will send it back to the server as json.

Here's my model in C# (which I got after converting the server xsd)

```
public class Tags
{
    public List<Tag> tagData { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string name {get; set;}
}
```

Here's my JSON string that is obtained from the server and an attempt at conversion to my model

```
//Json string obtained from server (hardcoded here for simplicity)
string json = "{tagData: {tags : [ { name : \"John\"}, { name : \"Sherlock\"}]}}";
//An attempt at conversion
var output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tags>(json);
```

This is the exception I get with the above code

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[jsonnetExample.Tag]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Path 'tagData.tags', line 1, position 17.
```

After understanding the above message I tried the following 2 things in the hope of fixing it.

A.I tried putting a JsonProperty to my first model.

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "tags")]
```

This didn't throw the exception anymore but the output tagData was null.

B. I modified my model as follows

```
public class Tags
{
    public WrapTag tagData { get; set; }
}

public class WrapTag
{
    public List<Tag> tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string name {get; set;}
}
```

This didn't throw any exception and populated the objects as expected. But Now I lost the one to one mapping between xsd(classes from the server) to my client model classes. Is it possible to get this deserialization working without the creation of the WrapTag class?

I would be very glad if someone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option, using `JObject.Parse`:

```
string json = "{tagData: {tags : [ { name : \"John\"}, { name : \"Sherlock\"}]}}";

List<Tag> tagList = JObject.Parse(json)["tagData"]["tags"].ToObject<List<Tag>>();
// or:
// List<Tag> tagList = JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("tagData.tags")
//    .ToObject<List<Tag>>();

Tags tags = new Tags { tagData = tagList };
```

Comment: Your solution works fine but it won't suit my requirement because the class "Tag" that I have has a lot of other properties like string name, int id etc. For simplicity I just choose to give one in this question. Manually converting each property inside that class would be difficult.

Comment: The properties in the `Tag` class should be converted automatically. Did you mean the `Tags` class?